# Как отправить textbox1.Text через smtp, если он многострочный?

Tags: c#, smtp, яндекс-почта

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress("myAddress@yandex.ru"); // Адрес отправителя
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("clientAddress@mail.ru")); // Адрес получателя
        mail.Subject = "Заголовок";
        mail.Body = textbox1.Text;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Host = "smtp.yandex.ru";
        client.Port = 587; // Обратите внимание что порт 587
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("address@yandex.ru", "password"); // Ваши логин и пароль
        client.Send(mail);


    }
```

Воспользовался этим кодом, но он отправляет только однострочные сообщения, что делать?

Comment: `mail.IsBodyHtml = false` [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: А покорректнее можно объяснение?